# Save data in table from different controller/view in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I want to have a view where a user can create a neighborhood. But, I want these neighborhoods to be approved by an admin before they are saved in the neighborhood table.

I would like to have a temp_neighborhood table, where the records will be saved until an admin approves them, then the data is moved to the neighborhoods table. This temp table will have the same attributes as the regular table.

So this is the flow I visualize:

- A user visits the neighborhoods/index page
- The user clicks a button to create their neighborhood
- They fill in the information, and the neighborhood controller takes that data, and saves it in the temp_neighborhood table.
- Later an admin will visit a page to approve/deny user created neighborhoods.
- Upon approval, a temporary neighborhood will be moved to the permanent neighborhoo table.

**Neighborhood controller:**

```
class NeighborhoodsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_neighborhood, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  #index, show, edit, update, and delete methods removed for brevity

  def new
    @neighborhood = Neighborhood.new
  end

  def create
    @neighborhood = Neighborhood.new(neighborhood_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @neighborhood.save
        format.html { redirect_to @neighborhood, notice: 'Neighborhood was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @neighborhood }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @neighborhood.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 private
    def set_neighborhood
      @neighborhood = Neighborhood.find_by_slug(params[:id])
    end

    def neighborhood_params
      params.require(:neighborhood).permit(:name, :address)
    end
end
```

**Neighborhood model:**

```
class Neighborhood < ActiveRecord::Base
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode

  has_many :users

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :address, presence: true
  after_validation :create_slug

  def to_param
    slug
  end

  private
    def create_slug
      self.slug = name.parameterize
    end
end
```

The above code just saves a user created neighborhood in the permanent table. To save the data in a temp table, I made the table and a controller named TempNeighborhood. The TempNeighborhood controller only had a new and create method, which looked just like the neighborhood controller.

Back in the neighborhood controller, in the create method I changed the following line:

```
@neighborhood = Neighborhood.new(neighborhood_params)
```

to this:

```
@neighborhood = TempNeighborhood.new(neighborhood_params)
```

However this gave me the following error:

```
uninitialized constant NeighborhoodsController::TempNeighborhood
```

What is the best way to go about saving data from one controller into another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you have the TempNeighborhood Controller set up as plural? TempNeighborhoods Controller and the Model is singular "TempNeighborhood".

Comment: That was indeed my problem. Cheers!